# iOS 11 Extra Space on NavigationBar

Tags: swift, autolayout, uinavigationbar, ios11

I changed my searchBar code from:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchNavigation.searchController.searchBar;
```

to:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.navigationItem.searchController = searchNavigation.searchController;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = NO;
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever;
} else {
    self.navigationItem.titleView = searchNavigation.searchController.searchBar;
}
```

but when try on ios 11 it looks like

[image]

there is extra space over searchBar and when i start to typing its slide top top and looks normal

[image]

Comment: I can't remember where but I read someone has added hack for this issue, 
        `self.navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.resignFirstResponder()`
     `self.navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()` add above two lines of code in viewWillAppear should work

Answer (score 1):

First for iOS 11 you are assigning your search controller to the navigation items searchController properties instead of as it's titleView.  If you do that then the search bar appears below the navigation bar as you have seen.

Second there is a property on the UISearchController called `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation` which controls whether the search bar moves up to hide the navigation bar when in use.

To replicate for iOS 11 what you have for previous versions do this instead:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    self.navigationItem.titleView = 
    searchNavigation.searchController.searchBar;   
    searchNavigation.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = NO;
    self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = UINavigationItemLargeTitleDisplayModeNever;
} else {
    self.navigationItem.titleView = 
    searchNavigation.searchController.searchBar;
}
```

Comment: I used `hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation `
 but still there is a space on searchBar. Is there anyway to remove this space. I tried code you post but it does not work for me.

Comment: Did you also change it for iOS 11 to assign it to the searchNavigation.titleView instead of the searchNavigation.searchController.  If you use the searchNavigation.searchController then the search bar gets put underneath the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

As previous answers have mentioned, setting the navigation bar's `searchController` as the desired search bar will produce the search bar sitting below the navigation bar's new "large title".

To stop this new behaviour you need to override the navigation bar's `titleView` with the search bar itself and disable the search controller's animation that hides the large title once input has started. This can be done like so:

```
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```